# Add HTML 5 data attribute to a newly created row when table is using datatable js

Tags: html, datatables

I have a HTML table with each row with HTML5 data attribute. The table is using [jQuery Datatables plug-in](http://www.datatables.net/). Now when I am adding a new row on a click of button how to add HTML5 data attribute to it again. The data attribute value is specified by the user.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Who could tell? Without a minimal example, showing how you insert the new row, no one can answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attribute write:

```
$('#categories-table').dataTable   
  'createdRow': (row, data, dataIndex) ->
     $(row).attr('data-category-id', data[0])
```

Data attribute read:

```
$('#categories-table tbody').on 'click','tr', () ->
  console.log $(this).data('category-id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell
that's a callback for once the cell is created so you can modify it and add your custom attributes or for the row http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow
(using the current v1.10.4)